# Given $X \sim e^x$ and $Y|X \sim x$ is uniform on $(0,x)$. Find the correlation of (X,Y)

Tags: statistics, correlation

Using $ f(x,y) = f_{X|Y} (Y|X) \ f_X (x)$ I got $\frac 1x  e^{-x}$ and I know that

$$ \operatorname{corr}(X,Y) = \frac{E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(Y)}}$$

but I'm struggling to calculate the expectations. My attempt for $E(XY)$ is

$$ E(XY) = \int_{x=1}^\infty\int_{y=0}^x ye^{-x}\ dy\ dx = (1-x)e^{-x} $$

and for $E(Y)$ I think it would be

$$ E(Y) = \int_{x=1}^{\infty}\int_{y=0}^x \frac{ye^{-x}}x\ dy\ dx $$

which would be zero and for $E(X)$ it looks like

$$ E(X) = \int_{x=1}^{\infty}\int_{y=0}^x e^{-x}\ dy\ dx $$

which would be zero, but this doesn't make much sense to me. Is there a flaw in my logic or is this just an odd problem?

Comment: How are you getting the integrals as zero? Show your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your calculation of the expectation of $XY$ cannot possibly be correct, since if $x > 1$, the result is negative.  The result must be a positive number for all admissible values of the parameter $x$.  Second, the expectation of $Y$ is also wrong, since $Y$ can never be negative, and has a positive probability of having a positive outcome; thus it must have positive expectation.  Third, the expectation of $X$ does not depend on $Y$.

I should also point out that your choice of notation is unfortunate, since I have assumed based on your calculations, that $x$ is a parameter for $X$, but if this is so, it is very confusing.  Therefore, in my response, I will use $\lambda$ for the **rate parameter** of $X$; i.e., $$f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, \quad x > 0, \quad \lambda > 0.$$

To rectify these issues, we begin with the last one.  If $X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda)$, we have $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \int_{x=0}^\infty x f_X(x) \, dx = \int_{x=0}^\infty \lambda x e^{-\lambda x} \, dx = \frac{1}{\lambda}.$$  This much should be familiar if you have studied the properties of the exponential distribution.

To compute the unconditional or marginal variance of $Y$, we observe by the law of total expectation $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]] = \operatorname{E}[X/2] = \operatorname{E}[X]/2 = \frac{1}{2\lambda}.$$  The second equality in the chain follows from hte fact that the conditional distribution of $Y \mid X$ is uniform on $(0,X)$, thus the conditional expectation is $(0 + X)/2 = X/2$.

To compute the expectation of $XY$, we again use the law of total expectation:  $$\operatorname{E}[XY] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[XY \mid X]] = \operatorname{E}[X(X/2)] = \operatorname{E}[X^2/2] = \frac{\operatorname{E}[X^2]}{2} = \frac{\operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{E}[X]^2}{2} = \frac{\operatorname{Var}[X] + \frac{1}{\lambda^2}}{2}.$$  We need to compute the variance of $X$, or recall that $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \frac{1}{\lambda^2},$$ the proof of which is left as an exercise.  Then we get $$\operatorname{E}[XY] = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}.$$  We have almost all of the pieces; the only remaining issue is to compute $\operatorname{Var}[Y]$.  This is obtained via the law of total variance:  $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]].$$  We recall that the variance of a uniform distribution on $(a,b)$ is simply $(b-a)^2/12$.  Therefore, $$\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X] = \frac{(X - 0)^2}{12} = \frac{X^2}{12},$$ hence $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \frac{\operatorname{E}[X^2]}{12} + \operatorname{Var}[X/2] = \frac{2/\lambda^2}{12} + \frac{\operatorname{Var}[X]}{4} = \frac{1}{6 \lambda^2} + \frac{1}{4\lambda^2} = \frac{5}{12\lambda^2}.$$  Then the correlation is $$\rho_{X,Y} = \frac{(1/\lambda^2) - (1/\lambda)(1/(2\lambda))}{\sqrt{(1/\lambda^2)(5/(12\lambda^2))}} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}.$$  No double integrals are needed, and note that the result is independent of $\lambda$.

Comment: How does E[XY|X] become X(X/2)?

Comment: @StruggleBus The expectation is taken with respect to the distribution of $Y$.  So if you understand that $\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X] = X/2$, then $\operatorname{E}[XY \mid X] = X(X/2)$ because it is computed with respect to $Y$, and $X$ is treated like an unknown constant.

Answer (score 0):

The values are not zero. Check your work

$$ \int_1^{\infty} \int_0^x y\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\ dy\ dx = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{xe^{-x}}{2}\ dx =\frac{1}{2}\big[-xe^{-x} - e^{-x}\big]\bigg|_1^\infty = e^{-1} $$

And similarly for the other integral